# First click on my datepicker is untracable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, date-range

I have forked a daterange picker, then customized (added features) on it as per my requirements. Here is the page: http://shekhardesigner.github.io/daterange/

Click on the second textbox - datepicker appears. You click on date cells - works fine. But if the  first click is on next prev (`<<` or `<` or `>>` or `>`) buttons - it does not function.

Method that is executing on those buttons clicks are:

```
clickNext:{},
clickPrev: {}
```

See full code here: https://github.com/shekhardesigner/daterange/blob/master/daterangepicker.js#L766

I am not able to trace what happens on first click. Any advise?

FYA, Repo: https://github.com/shekhardesigner/daterange